# ¿Cómo contar los elementos vacíos de dos columnas con laravel 6.0?

Tags: laravel

Tengo dos columnas en las cuales quisiera contar de la siguiente manera:

si en las dos columnas no existe ningún dato en la linea, añadir un número al conteo. Estoy intentando hacer un conteo de las veces que no haya ningún dato en las dos columnas.

He intentado con este código pero no me ha funcionado:

```
$individuales = DB::table('incidencias')
    ->where('inc_padre', '=', '')
    ->orWhere('nro_ticket' '=', '')
    ->count(DB::raw('(inc_padre), (nro_ticket)'));
```

he podido hacerlo con una sola columna, de esta manera

```
$ccr = DB::table('incidencias')
    ->where('nro_ticket', '=', '') 
    ->count(DB::raw('nro_ticket'));
```

Pero ahora necesito hacerlo con dos columnas a la vez.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: Creo que para estas cosas, es mejor o lanzar directamente las sentencias de sql o recoger los datos y llevar la lógica a la programación.

Comment: ya lo hice pero con una sola columna... con este código $ccr = DB::table('incidencias')
        ->where('nro_ticket', '=', '') 
        ->count(DB::raw('nro_ticket'));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rápidamente se me ocurre simplemente usar los dos where con "And" en vez de Or, y contar los registros.

```
$individuales = DB::table('incidencias')
    ->where('nro_ticket', '')
    ->where('inc_padre', '')
    ->count();
```

De esta forma, solo se contarán los registros que tienen los dos campos vacíos.

Comment: muchisimas gracias, no se me habia ocurrido